# How can I configure all my new rails apps to use quiet assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I find myself having to create the config/initializers/quiet_assets.rb file every time I create a new app. Is there some way I can configure rails core on my development box to always create this file when I create a new app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found https://github.com/evrone/quiet_assets which seems to do the trick!